# How to set linetype for geom_vline in a faceted plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

The following code works like a charm:

```
foo = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),
                 y=c(4,5,6),
                 lt=c('dotted', 'dashed', 'dotdash'))
ggplot(foo, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=x, linetype=lt))
```

[image]

The following code drops linetype.  Why?

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=3, aes(linetype=lt)) +
  facet_wrap(~lt)
```

[image]

I am using ggplot 0.9.3.1 in Rstudio.

Comment: Try: `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3, linetype = lt))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm your problem and also that Sandy's comment fixes it for me, using ggplot2 1.0 in R 3.1.2:

```
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3, linetype = lt))
```

However I still think this is a bug in (maybe just the documentation for) `geom_vline`.  I think `xintercept` should be listed as a required aesthetic with a default value of 0.  Notably, the code below "works" -- the lines have the correct hashing at the default x location of 0:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x,y)) + 
   geom_point() +
   geom_vline(aes(linetype=lt)) +
   facet_wrap(~lt)
```

So the problem seems to be that when required aesthetics are supplied outside of `aes()`, the arguments inside of `aes()` are ignored.  This is different than other functions.  For example,

```
ggplot(foo) + geom_point(x=1, aes(y=y))
```

gives an error but

```
ggplot(foo) + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=y))
```

does not.  As far as I'm concerned, ideal behavior would be for `geom_vline()` to  behave the same way as `geom_point()` in this regard.